# iOS App Rejection 2.10 error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

My app rejected because of error 2.10 which I showed it below. So I search for answers about this error and tried to launch app in Ipad simulator. When it runs on ipad it fills whole screen but it should be iphone screen because app is only for iphone. I disabled both auto sizes and size classes to check that but problem still remains. Any Idea what I did miss to check ?

Both settings  and rejection mail screenshots are here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It means your app looks bad on iPad. iPhone-only apps must support running in iPhone 3GS/4 mode on the iPad.

Comment: How can I enable to support running like iphone 4 mode on ipad ? Is there a setting to enable ?

Comment: No, but check your app works fine on the iPhone 4 simulator and provide 1x assets.

Comment: It works fine on iphone 4 and all assets were already provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should dispute this and refer to bug #18371031.

This was an error in iOS 8 that is fixed in iOS 8.1.

Comment: I am downloading the 8.1 SDK atm. I will update question status after I check that. Thank you for your information